# peewee: building a query programmatically

Tags: sql, peewee, flask-peewee

Is it possible (how?) to build a select query programmatically in peewee? The point is to add .where() clauses as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
query = SomeThing.select()
if foo:
    query = query.where(SomeThing.value == 'foo')
else:
    query = query.where(...)
```